# Install Samba package from ISO file or CDROM

Tags: ubuntu, samba, file-server, data-cd

I have an old server which is running Ubuntu Linux 16.04 in a lab environment. It is not not possible to upgrade to the new Ubuntu version due to hardware capacity. I decided to keep it and us it as normal (security issue is not a problem).

I need to install samba package but I can't get this package from the repository anymore. I have an ISO file of this distro and also burn into a CDROM. I have checked the document about select the CDROM as the source of installation but when I tried to do that the system still keep asking me to connect to internet.

I tried to review the configuration file many time but seem nothing wrong but I still can't install the samba package from this media.

If anyone has any solution please kindly let me know how I can fix this problem or is there any offline .deb package that I can't install samba on my Linux?

Thank, Kanel

Comment: "security issue is not a problem" - yes, it is. Have you tried mounting the ISO/CD and installing with dpkg? You'll need to untangle the dependencies by hand.

Comment: You've checked which documentation exactly? To prevent `apt` from trying to access the internet just comment out all internet sources from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. This article should get you sorted: https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/08/12/ubuntu-16-04-install-package-from-dvd/